# CircleCI: Execute local binary

Tags: linux, bash, circleci

I'd like to be able to access my local `bin` files on CircleCI. Simply exporting a new PATH variable doesn't seem to be working. The following works locally, but does not work on CircleCI. On CircleCI, the variable is unchanged.

**circle.yml**

```
machine:
  pre:
    - echo $PATH
    - export PATH=$PATH:./bin
    - echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be interpolating in the machine:environment section.

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: $PATH:./bin
```